# how to redirect to particular report based on parameter selected in dropdown in SSRS?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

i would like the user to redirect to particular report based on the parameter selected in dropdown. suppose i have a dropdown with names of 4 report names like A,B,C,D. if user selects A then the report A need to be displayed. Along with this 3 parameters which are common to all reports need to be passed. can this be done? aprreciate your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this can be done *exactly* as you describe in SSRS alone, since redirecting to a particular report is an "action" - simply running one report is not an "action" in SSRS terms.

The following possibilities occur to me:

- combine all four existing reports into a single report, with their displayed report objects conditionally suppressed based on the value of the report name parameter; or
- instead of having a parameter for the report name, have a report with the other three parameters that displays report objects with actions linking to each of the four existing reports (essentially, this report would be a dummy report whose only purpose is to provide navigation to the other reports); or
- write custom asp code to do this, instead of trying to do it in SSRS alone.

Comment: Thanks Mark I hope this works out for my issue. It would be better if you can share any  abstract sample for this.

Comment: @Uneverno: I don't see how I can add samples without them being specific, rather than abstract. Can you explain which aspect of my answer needs clarification? Have you decided on which approach you want to take, or is this subject to further clarification?